# I am trying to send a email in meteor with process.env and smtp gmail

Tags: javascript, meteor, smtp, gmail, mailgun

I am using the following to send emails which works on localhost but not my server.

```
// server
Meteor.startup(function () {
    process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://uername%40gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465/"; 
});
```

I get the follow error in my logs(it seems like google is blocking it for some reason, **is there a way to stop that?**

```
[162.243.52.235] 534-5.7.14 Learn more at
534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 l10sm1017845qae.41 - gsmtp
    at SMTPClient._actionAUTHComplete (/opt/meteor/app/programs/server/npm/email/main/node_modules/simplesmtp/lib/client.js:826:23)
    at SMTPClient._onData (/opt/meteor/app/programs/server/npm/email/main/node_modules/simplesmtp/lib/client.js:329:29)
    at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at CleartextStream.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at _stream_readable.js:401:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

This is the event that I think sends initiates the email sending. I know that meteor is now setup to use mailgun, **is there a way to modify this to just use mailgun instead of meteor without process.env?**

```
Template.forgotPassword.events({
    'submit #forgotPasswordForm': function(e, t) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var forgotPasswordForm = $(e.currentTarget),
            email = trimInput(forgotPasswordForm.find('#forgotPasswordEmail').val().toLowerCase());

        if (isNotEmpty(email) && isEmail(email)) {
            Accounts.forgotPassword({email: email}, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    if (err.message === 'User not found [403]') {
                        Session.set('alert', 'This email does not exist.');
                    } else {
                        Session.set('alert', 'We\'re sorry but something went wrong.');
                    }
                } else {
                    Session.set('alert', 'Email Sent. Please check your mailbox to reset your password.');

                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    },

    'click #returnToSignIn': function(e, t) {
        Session.set('showForgotPassword', null);
        return false;
    },
});
```

Packages already installed

[image]

Comment: You should not include clear-text (or uri-encoded) passwords in app code. Better to set an environment variable (more secure).
Better still--enable 2-factor authentication (for gmail) and then setup an app password (see https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833 ).  That way if your app or server is compromised, your gmail account is not and you can revoke app access.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to URL encode your username and password else Meteor confuses the two '@' signs with each other.

You could do this in your JS console (with `encodeURIComponent(username)`) and usually end up with something like

```
user%40gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465
```

You could use Mailgun in the same way, or Mandrill, or any other smtp provider. It's just the username format causing the issues.

Comment: Unfortuantely I tried that before and that didnt work, but it is that way now. I still get the error in my logs basically telling me google denied me [162.243.52.235] 534-5.7.14 Learn more at
534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 c2sm1240459qan.18 - gsmtp

Comment: Does your password have any of `@`, `:`, `.` in it?

Comment: just words and numbers, no special characters.

Comment: I've edited Anders' question to not detract from the real problem due to the double @ problem. Is this answer still useful?

Answer (score 9):

I encountered a similar problem. The method send email work locally but not on the hosting modulus. For my part this was due to a blocking google security (access to my gmail account from Seattle while I live in France has probably seemed fishy to google). I went through several pages to authorize less strict connections to my gmail account.
On [this page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/notifications) I saw the blockage. So [I allowed the less secure applications](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and [allowed access to my account](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha).

If it helps someone ..

Comment: God, that wasn't obvious. 
Many thanks for sharing this

Comment: This was my issue as well, here you have a guide about how to allow less secure apps. https://hotter.io/docs/email-accounts/secure-app-gmail/

Answer (score 5):

Just use the email package with

`meteor add email`

Then sending email will work. Mine works with port 587 in my config.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://user%40gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:587';
});
```

Comment: I have email installed and port 587 is just giving me more errors in my logs.

Comment: This approach is inadvisable if the above code is in your repo. Preferably, you pass the MAIL_URL in your settings.json file. Also, the port should 465.