# Is there a way to send emails while testing my meteor app locally?

Tags: javascript, email, meteor

Hi so i'm very new to coding and have taught myself so please forgive me if this comes across as a really dumb question.

Basically I am building a web app, just something I want to try out. I have installed the meteor email package and follow the docs as well as I could, but all seem to involve running a smtp server such as mailgun.

I was wanting to find out if is there anyway to run a localhost version, I dont want to signup for things like mailgun at the moment I just want to testing the emails and have them send to my personal email. Is there a way or would I have to set up something through say mailgun?

Again sorry about what I am sure is a pretty simple answer, but all the googling I have done doesnt seem to help me get any closer to an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Gmail account you can easily use it for sending emails. You have to set `MAIL_URL` variable, to something like that:

`smtps://username%40gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465`

At this moment although you have correct username and password you won't be able to send emails because of Google security rules. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31875371/3648015) you have to [allow the less secure applications](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and [allow access to your account](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha). After this steps, you should be able to send emails from your Meteor application.

Comment: Thank you very much will give it a go and see what happens. Thank you!