# Meteor email error for gmail server

Tags: meteor, gmail, meteor-accounts

My server.js file contains the following code segments which should configure a gmail address and send an email.

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtps://email_address@gmail.com:password_without_special_keys@smtp.gmail.com:465';

    Email.send({
        from: "from_adddress@gmail.com",
        to: "to_address@gmail.com",
        subject: "Meteor Can Send Emails via Gmail",
        text: "Its pretty easy to send emails via gmail."
    })



});
```

Shouldn't my meteor app send an email when i run the app with the command

meteor

??
But it is providing the following errors. What's wrong?

```
W20170718-15:36:37.701(6)? (STDERR) /home/forhadmethun/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.1.dvn6c8++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
W20170718-15:36:37.766(6)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);
W20170718-15:36:37.767(6)? (STDERR)                                             ^
W20170718-15:36:37.769(6)? (STDERR) 
W20170718-15:36:37.769(6)? (STDERR) Error: Connection timeout
W20170718-15:36:37.770(6)? (STDERR)     at Object.Future.wait (/home/forhadmethun/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.1.dvn6c8++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
W20170718-15:36:37.771(6)? (STDERR)     at Mail._syncSendMail (packages/meteor.js:213:24)
W20170718-15:36:37.772(6)? (STDERR)     at smtpSend (packages/email.js:116:13)
W20170718-15:36:37.773(6)? (STDERR)     at Object.Email.send (packages/email.js:174:5)
W20170718-15:36:37.774(6)? (STDERR)     at server/main.js:28:11
W20170718-15:36:37.775(6)? (STDERR)     at Function.time (/home/forhadmethun/WebstormProjects/EmailSEndProject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:309:28)
W20170718-15:36:37.776(6)? (STDERR)     at /home/forhadmethun/WebstormProjects/EmailSEndProject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:347:13
W20170718-15:36:37.777(6)? (STDERR)     at /home/forhadmethun/WebstormProjects/EmailSEndProject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:388:5
W20170718-15:36:37.779(6)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/home/forhadmethun/WebstormProjects/EmailSEndProject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
W20170718-15:36:37.780(6)? (STDERR)     at /home/forhadmethun/WebstormProjects/EmailSEndProject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:386:11
W20170718-15:36:37.781(6)? (STDERR)     - - - - -
W20170718-15:36:37.782(6)? (STDERR)     at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/forhadmethun/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.3.3ikb16++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/node4mailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:558:19)
W20170718-15:36:37.784(6)? (STDERR)     at SMTPConnection._onError (/home/forhadmethun/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.3.3ikb16++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/node4mailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:531:20)
W20170718-15:36:37.785(6)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/forhadmethun/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.3.3ikb16++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/node4mailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:249:18)
W20170718-15:36:37.787(6)? (STDERR)     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `MAIL_URL` variable should look like

```
smtps://username%40gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465
```

If this won't help, you will need to [allow the less secure applications](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and [allow access to your account](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha). This steps if done correctly should allow sending emails from Gmail. You can read more about Gmail security rules by looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391691/i-am-trying-to-send-a-email-in-meteor-with-process-env-and-smtp-gmail/31875371#31875371).